# AttachInterrupt on ESP8266 with Arduino Firmware

Tags: android, c, interrupt, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to figure out how the `AttachedInterrupt` works on the NodeMCU. Everything I found tells me that this code is OK?!

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(D4, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(D4, doSth(), CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(digitalRead(D4));
  delay(100);
}

void doSth() {
  Serial.println("Check!");
}
```

But I just get this error:

[image]

I still have no idea after hours of research!

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Comment: I have not used interrupts, but it looks to me like the `doSth()` is being called rather than passed.  I think it should be `doSth`.

Comment: Genius! That's it :) Thank you veeeery much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved — Thanks again!

I just used `attachInterrupt(D4, doSth, CHANGE);`

instead of `attachInterrupt(D4, doSth(), CHANGE);`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use serial print(s) inside an ISR. Move it to your Loop().